# Does iChat screen sharing over the internet work in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, sharing, screen, ichat, screen-sharing

If I upgrade to Lion, will I still be able to use iChat to take over my elderly father's Mac (we have MobileMe accounts) to help him with problems and software updates? I read in some forums that this is broken in Lion, but I don't know if those were isolated incidents or not. Kindly requesting that gracious Lion iChat users test this and report results here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used it today. Lion to Snow Leopard and Lion to Lion. Worked fine. I didn't even think about it not working until I read this… :-)

Comment: I have read people having issues with direct screen sharing (vnc) but iChat works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I also have the problem screensharing a Lion machine viewed on a Snow Leopard machine, but not the other way around. I stumbled on a fix. If you first start a video chat and then start screen sharing while the video chat is underway, it is able to connect. I was able to verify this several tries with it not working unless I first video chat.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me Lion->Lion and Lion->Snow Leopard. So if you can do it now on then you probably won't have a problem.

Comment: is this Lion to snow leopard, or...?

Comment: It works for me on Lion->SL or Lion->Lion.

Answer (score 1):

It also still works with Leopard, as I have tested with my parents' PPC iMac.

Comment: Great news, it's very useful to hear about functionality with older OS's, thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1):

iChat screen share from Snow Leopard to Lion don't work for me. Lion to Snow Leopard is ok.